# Differences between DLNA 1.5 and 2.0

Tags: dlna

I'm scratching my head trying to understand which are the differences between `DLNA 1.5` and `2.0`.
Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

-- Paolo

Answer (score 1):

The DLNA versions are the scope of DLNA specifications. Each version adds new specifications and there is increase in scope. Here is a brief overview.

**Version 1.0**

- 2 volumes: Architecture & Protocols, Media Formats
- 2 Device Classes: DMP, DMS
- About 50 media format profiles

**Version 1.5**

- 3 volumes: Architecture & Protocols, Media Formats, and Link
  Protection
- 12 Devices Classes and 5 Device Capabilities
- About 250 media format profiles

**Version 2.0**

- Includes topics like EPG, Content Sync, RUI, WPS, Media Formats, Scheduled recording, DRM